# What would one see, if they looked at a system in energy eigenstate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry-breaking, wavefunction-collapse

We know, time evolution of energy eigenstates is extremely simple $\psi(t)=\psi(0)e^{-iEt}$. On the other hand we have symmetry breaking. Here I present an interesting thought experiment, and wonder what one is going to observe in it.

Let us consider a closed mini-universe, that has a size of our solar system, the same average energy as our solar system and the same amount of other conserved stuff like various charges. The difference though is that this mini-universe, unlike our solar system, is in an eigenstate.

The question: what are we going to see when we look at such mini-universe? Are we going to see a uniform gas, or are we going to see a star, planets and lots of complexity?

And if the answer is that we are going to see a dilute gas, what is going to happen next to it? Is it going to start collapsing and forming a star and planets after we observe it? It seems fascinating to think that a single observation can essentially "create" the universe.